# Intel NUC No Sound - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound, 16.04

This problem seems to be fixed with these instructions for previous versions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Does anyone knows if .deb (amd64) file will be uploaded for ubuntu 16.04?

https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages